# Issues loading different levels randomly in Unity-3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, random

I need to create a class (or classes, if need be) that loads levels randomly every time the user clicks on the "Next Button" and once all levels have been loaded, we stop loading and close the application. I got the code set up but I am still not getting the result I am looking for which is:

1. User clicks on a button.
2. Load a random level
3. That levels gets stored in an array list
4. Once the user is done with that level he/she presses the "Load Next Level" button
5. Load the next random level
6. But first, we check if the random level is not the same as before.
7. If it's not, then we repeat steps 2-5, else we go to step 8
8. If the levels have all been visited then we quit the application

The problem I am having is that my game loads the same level every time I hit play and it doesn't go to the next scene after I am done with the current one. This is what I have so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class SceneManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool userClickedNextButton;   //This flag is raised by the other classes that have the GUI button logic

    protected const int MAX = 2;

    private ArrayList scenesWereAlreadyLoaded = new ArrayList();

    void Update()
    {
        if (userClickedNextButton)
        {
                //by default the game starts at 0 so I want to be able to 
                //randomly call the next two scenes in my game. There will
                //be more levels but for now I am just testing two
                int sceneToLoad = Random.Range(1, 2);
                if (!scenesWereAlreadyLoaded.Contains(sceneToLoad))
                {
                    scenesWereAlreadyLoaded.Add(sceneToLoad);
                    Application.LoadLevel(sceneToLoad);
                }
                userClickedNextButton = false;

        }
        if (scenesWereAlreadyLoaded.Count > MAX) { Application.Quit(); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a list with your level numbers, then remove the currently loaded level. You repeat that until the list is empty.

Also don't use `ArrayList`, it's very old and deprecated type, from the ages before .NET/Mono had Generic support. Better use a Generic `List<T>`, which is type safe and faster than `ArrayList`.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class SceneManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    // not best idea to have it static 
    public static bool userClickedNextButton;

    protected const int MAX = 50;

    private List<int> scenes = new List<int>();
    void Start() {
        // Initialize the list with levels
        scenes = new List<int>(Enumerable.Range(1,MAX)); // This creates a list with values from 1 to 50
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (userClickedNextButton)
        {
            if(scenes.Count == 0) {
                // No scenes left, quit
                Application.Quit();
            }

            // Get a random index from the list of remaining level 
            int randomIndex = Random.Range(0, scenes.Count);
            int level = scenes[randomIndex];
            scenes.RemoveAt(randomIndex); // Removes the level from the list
            Application.LoadLevel(level);

            userClickedNextButton = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's giving me an error when I try and use IEnumerable. Am I missing a scope declaration?

Comment: `using System.Linq`, though that would be easy to find out by looking at the MSDN Documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.range(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: You should also add `using using System.Collections` and for that case `using System.Collections.Generic` since `IEnumerable<int>` (I updated the code above, because it wasn't an int. But you should really first learn the basics of C# before continue to write a game. Knowing how to import or use MSDN to look for which namespaces are required is the most basic of programming in .NET

Comment: Sorry, fixed it now. `Enumerable.Range` it is. I don't have VS/Unity3D at work, so I was writing it from top of my head

Comment: You could try moving `Application.LoadLevel(level)` to the end, since the flag is set back to false only after that which may never happen and the value is never set back, because it's static. Is your SceneManager set as "DontDestoryOnLoad"? http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html If your object gets destroyed and recreated on each scene load, then the list gets populated a new. Your scene manager has to persist for the whole lifetime of your game

Comment: See my comment from above. Make sure your object is **NOT DESTROYED** on scene load and that the scenes do not create new objects of that kind (look for a singleton-like pattern for use with Unity/MonoBehaviours)

Comment: Fixed It! What I was doing wrong was that I had the same script on all 3 main camera scenes and they were not talking to each other. Basically every time the boolean got called it just calld the same function 3 times so it would never finish. Thank you again, you wer a lot of help!!! You totally deserve all that reputation and the up votes I gave you. Happy holidays!

Answer (score 2):

As per the Unity3D documentation (http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Random.Range.html), range returns an integer between min (included) and max (excluded), so, in your case, Random.Range(1,2) will always returns 1.

Try with this

```
int = sceneToLoad = Random.Range(1,3)
```

Comment: In the Randon.Range(1,3) or where?

Comment: well of course a 2 will throw an exception when the array/list has a length of 2

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to do so. You can prepare an array with random unique numbers. When you want to load a new level just increment the index of the array. 
Here's a code that can help:(Attach this script to an empty gameobject in your first scene)

```
  using UnityEngine;
  using System.Collections;


  public class MoveToRandomScene : MonoBehaviour {
  public Texture nextButtonTexture; // set this in the inspector 
  public static int[] arrScenes;
  public static int index;
  void Start () {
    index = 0;
    arrScenes = GenerateUniqueRandom (10, 0, 10); //assuming you have 10 levels starting from 0.

}

void OnGUI {
// Load the first element of the array
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect (0,0,Screen.width/4,Screen.height/4),nextButtonTexture))
    {
    int level = arrScenes [0] ;
    Application.LoadLevel (level);
    }
}
//Generate unique numbers (levels) in an array
public int[] GenerateUniqueRandom(int amount, int min, int max)
{
    int[] arr = new int[amount];
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        bool done = false;
        while (!done)
        {
            int num = Random.Range(min, max);
            int j = 0;
            for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                if (num == arr[j])
                {
                    break;    
                }
            }
            if (j == i)
            {
                arr[i] = num;
                done = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

}

For the other scenes you just need to create this script and attach it to an empty game object whenever you want to load a new random scene:

```
void OnGUI {
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect (0,0,Screen.width/4,Screen.height/4),nextButtonTexture))
    {
       if (MoveToRandomScene.index == 9) {
       // Load again your first level
       Application.LoadLevel(0);
    }
    // else you continue loading random levels
    else {
    MoveToRandomScene.index++;
    int level = MoveToRandomScene.arrScenes[MoveToRandomScene.index];
    Application.LoadLevel(level);
    }
 }
}
```